# How to get the current combination id of a product?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

How can I get the id of the current combination displayed to the user?

Comment: if you mean .tpl files just use {$product.id_product_attribute} in pages wich contain products

Comment: @AlexanderGrosul Yes, this is what I was looking for. And now I also know from inside a hook you could use `Tools::getValue('id_product_attribute')`. Could you please add that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean .tpl files just use {$product.id_product_attribute} in pages wich contain products

Comment: How to get in front/ProductController.php file?